# How to get a count going inside a Knockout foreach loop?

Tags: knockout.js

I have a standard foreach, and the loop is working correctly:

```
<!-- m7ko foreach: MyCollection -->
   <div id="panel1" />
<!-- /m7ko -->
```

Just to simplify, all I want to do is change the static id's of `panel1` to `panel1`, `panel2`, `panel3`, etc as it loops.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the `$index` and the `attr` binding. Something like this

```
<div data-bind='attr: { id: 'panel' + $index() + 1 }'></div>
```

where `$index` is the current position of that element in the KO observable array. 
It's probably cleaner to put that in a computed observable though, but the logic is pretty much the same.

Comment: Yup that worked nicely, needed to adjust your syntax a bit, but the overall concept worked.